# Create a procedure to get grouped by data from a table to another given a certain year and quarter in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, datetime, procedure

I am trying to get this code to work. I want to create a procedure that given a certain year and quarter it fills a table (tb_quarter) with grouped by information of another two tables.

So far I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_calc_quarter 
(year tb_quarter.year%type, quarter tb_quarter.quarter%type) AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tb_quarter
        SELECT
            EXTRACT(quarter FROM l.last_update_date) AS quarter,
            EXTRACT(year FROM l.last_update_date) AS year,
            cust_no,
            ROUND(l.iva_amount/l.net_amount*100) AS iva_percent,
            SUM(l.iva_amount) AS amount
        FROM 
            tb_lines l
        INNER JOIN
            tb_invoice i USING (invoice_id)
        GROUP BY
            cust_no,
            iva_percent,
            year,
            quarter;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

So far, the procedure works to fill in the table, but without taking into account the year and quarter I put in.

I am unable to solve the code in order to select only the data that matches the year and the quarter.

I've tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_calc_quarter 
    (year tb_quarter.year%type, quarter tb_quarter.quarter%type) AS $$
BEGIN
        SELECT
            EXTRACT(quarter FROM l.last_update_date) AS l_quarter,
            EXTRACT(year FROM l.last_update_date) AS l_year,
            cust_no,
            ROUND(l.iva_amount/l.net_amount*100) AS iva_percent,
            SUM(l.iva_amount) AS amount
        FROM 
            tb_lines l
        INNER JOIN
            tb_invoice i USING (invoice_id)
        WHERE l_quarter = quarter
            AND l_year = year
        GROUP BY
            cust_no,
            iva_percent,
            l_year,
            l_quarter;
        INSERT INTO tb_quarter VALUES (quarter,year,iva_percent,amount);
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

But it returns an error saying the column l_quarter doesn't exist. I've also tried to change the names of the input parameters (year + quarter), but it also returns error saying it is not allowed.

These are the tables I am working with:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_quarter 
(
    quarter INTEGER NOT NULL,
    year INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cust_no CHARACTER (5) NOT NULL,
    iva_percent INTEGER NOT NULL,
    amount REAL NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_tb_quarter PRIMARY KEY(quarter, year, cust_no, iva_percent),
    CONSTRAINT  fk_tb_customer FOREIGN KEY (cust_no) REFERENCES tb_customer(cust_no)
);

CREATE TABLE erp.tb_lines (
invoice_id            INT NOT NULL,
line_id               INT  NOT NULL,
line_num              INT NOT NULL,
item                  CHARACTER(5),
description           CHARACTER VARYING(120)  NOT NULL,
net_amount            REAL NOT NULL,
iva_amount            REAL NOT NULL,
last_updated_by       CHARACTER VARYING(20) DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
last_update_date      DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_lines PRIMARY KEY (line_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_lines_invoice FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES erp.tb_invoice (invoice_id)
```

);

```
 CREATE TABLE erp.tb_invoice (
co_code            CHARACTER(3) NOT NULL,
invoice_id         INT NOT NULL,
invoice_no         CHARACTER VARYING(15)  NOT NULL,
cust_no            CHARACTER(5) NOT NULL,
site_id            INT NOT NULL,
payed              CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
net_amount         REAL NOT NULL,
iva_amount         REAL NOT NULL,
tot_amount         REAL NOT NULL,
last_updated_by    CHARACTER VARYING(20) DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
last_update_date   DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_invoice PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_company FOREIGN KEY (co_code) REFERENCES erp.tb_company (co_code),
CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_customer FOREIGN KEY (cust_no) REFERENCES erp.tb_customer (cust_no),
CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_site FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES erp.tb_site (site_id)
```

);

Finally I was able to solve it using nbk's answer and changing it a little bit:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_calc_quarter
    (year tb_quarter.year%type, quarter tb_quarter.quarter%type) AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tb_quarter
        SELECT
            EXTRACT(quarter FROM l.last_update_date) AS l_quarter,
            EXTRACT(year FROM l.last_update_date) AS l_year,
            cust_no,
            ROUND(l.iva_amount/l.net_amount*100) AS iva_percent,
            SUM(l.iva_amount) AS amount
        FROM 
            tb_lines l
        INNER JOIN
            tb_invoice i USING (invoice_id)
        WHERE 
            EXTRACT(quarter FROM l.last_update_date) = quarter
            AND EXTRACT(year FROM l.last_update_date) = year
        GROUP BY
            cust_no,
            iva_percent,
            l_year,
            l_quarter;
        
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres doesn't support using aliases anywhere, so you could simply repeat the extract

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_calc_quarter 
(_year tb_quarter.year%type, _quarter tb_quarter.quarter%type) AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tb_quarter
        SELECT
            EXTRACT(quarter FROM l.last_update_date) AS l_quarter,
            EXTRACT(year FROM l.last_update_date) AS l_year,
            cust_no,
            ROUND(l.iva_amount/l.net_amount*100) AS iva_percent,
            SUM(l.iva_amount) AS amount
        FROM 
            tb_lines l
        INNER JOIN
            tb_invoice i USING (invoice_id)
        WHERE 
        EXTRACT(quarter FROM l.last_update_date) = _quarter
               AND EXTRACT(year FROM l.last_update_date) = _year;
        GROUP BY
            cust_no,
            iva_percent,
            year,
            quarter
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you! I made a couple of changes and it works.

Comment: If that answer essentially solved your issue then kindly accept it.  This aids future questioners having essentially the  same issue and removes the question from the unresolved list. Please do not leave an answered question in the unanswered queue.

Comment: @Belayer for such a comment i received a moderator email and notice, so don't do it

Comment: Well that seems strange but OK.

Comment: @nbk: I do sometimes add this kind of comment as well (although I wait at least one day). I have never received any moderator mail regarding that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name like i said last week some moderarator send and email and i got the notice, maybe it is only me, but some people are handpicked and then get the message.